# Trix editor define custom attachment styles

Tags: javascript, html, css, trix

I added an image to the Trix editor, generating the following code:

```
<figure 
    data-trix-attachment="{lots of data}" 
    data-trix-content-type="image/jpeg"
    data-trix-attributes="{'presentation':'gallery'}" 
    class="attachment attachment--preview attachment--jpg">
    <img src="http://myhost/myimage.jpg" width="5731" height="3821">
    <figcaption class="attachment__caption">
        <span class="attachment__name">cool.jpg</span> <span class="attachment__size">4.1 MB</span>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

When I display the generated HTML from the editor on my Bootstrap-based page, the image obviously extends the screen (see the `width` and `height`) and I'd like to remove these props and also assign the `img-fluid` class to it.

So basically I thought to use the config:

```
Trix.config.css.attachment = 'img-fluid'
```

But that does a) not change the `attachment` class to `img-fluid` and it also would not apply the changes to the image but the `figure`.

I would like to avoid using jQuery each time I display the content and traverse all `figures` and then manipulate the image's properties at runtime.

Isn't there a solution to define these styles when adding the attachment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Trix](https://github.com/basecamp/trix) does not have any kind of support to change the image element inside the attachment. One way to do it is by using [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to check for mutations inside Trix editor that apply to `attributes`, `childList` and `subtree`.

If we have a `width` or `height` `attributes` mutation to an `img` target node with a `figure` parent node, then we remove those attributes and we can apply the class `img-fluid` to the first attribute mutation, for example `width`.

#### Run code snippet and try to add some image attachments to see or inspect the HTML

<sup>*Please read inline comments*</sup>

```js
// Listen to trix-attachment-add event so we'll get rid of the progress bar just for this demo
// Here we should upload the attachment and handle progress properly
document.addEventListener("trix-attachment-add", event => {
  const { attachment } = event.attachment;
 
  // Get rid of the progress bar
  attachment.setUploadProgress(100)
});


// Get the Trix editor
const editor = document.querySelector('trix-editor');

// Instantiating an observer
const observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(({ type, target, attributeName }) => {
    
    // If the parent is a figure with an img target
    if (target.parentNode.tagName === 'FIGURE' && 
        target.nodeName === 'IMG')
    {
      if (type === 'attributes') {
        switch(attributeName) {

          // If we have attribute width
          case 'width':
            // Remove attribute width
            target.removeAttribute('width');
            // Add img-fluid only once
            target.classList.add('img-fluid');
            break;

          // If we have attribute height
          case 'height':
            // Remove attribute height
            target.removeAttribute('height');
            break;
        }
      }

      // Render images HTML code
      renderHtmlOutput();
    }

  });
});

// Observing Trix Editor
observer.observe(editor, {
  attributes: true,
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
});

// Function to render every figure > img HTML code
function renderHtmlOutput() {
  const images = editor.querySelectorAll('figure > img');
  let output = '';

  for(const image of images) {
    output += image.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, "\n  ") + "\n";
  }

  document.getElementById('output-html').textContent = output;
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 10px;
}

#editor-container {
  flex: 3;
}

#output-container {
  flex: 2;
  margin-left: 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid lightgray;
  overflow: auto;
}

#output-html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: small;
  color: blue;
}

/* Hide some Trix buttons to free horizontal space */
.trix-button--icon-increase-nesting-level,
.trix-button--icon-decrease-nesting-level,
.trix-button--icon-bullet-list,
.trix-button--icon-number-list { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.2.1/trix.js" integrity="sha256-2D+ZJyeHHlEMmtuQTVtXt1gl0zRLKr51OCxyFfmFIBM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.2.1/trix.css" integrity="sha256-yebzx8LjuetQ3l4hhQ5eNaOxVLgqaY1y8JcrXuJrAOg=" crossorigin="anonymous"/>

<section id="main">
  <div id="editor-container">
    <form>
      <input id="editor" value="Editor content goes here" type="hidden" name="content">
      <trix-editor input="editor"></trix-editor>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="output-container">
    <pre id="output-html"></pre>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: can you possibly explain this using react? @christoslytras

Comment: @ertemishakk there is nothing special using `MutationObserver` in React, you just do it by using refs made with `useRef` hook. If you want to make things easier, there is a hook you can use for `MutationObserver` itself and you can find details about installation and usage here [@rooks/use-mutation-observer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rooks/use-mutation-observer).

Comment: why does your code adds img-fluid to only first added attachment? @christoslytras

Comment: @ertemishakk it doesn't add it on the first attachment, it adds it **on one of the attributes of each attachment found**, don't you see what purpose the `switch/case` is there for? It's for **attributes**, it writes `switch(attributeName)` so it's obviously for the image attributes; so, we only add the class `img-fluid` to the **width attribute** because **we want to add it just once** and don't waste CPU cycles on adding twice a class that already exists.